# Custom WordPress stylesheet not loading

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I went through the many other threads on this topic, but none of it seems to work for me.

I'm trying to make my own WordPress theme, but I keep getting this error:

```
GET http:/ /placeholder-url.net/wp-content/themes/awesomethemecss/awesome.css?ver=1.0.0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Here's the php:

```
function load_my_stylesheets() { 
wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . 'css/awesome.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all'); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_stylesheets');
```

That's my test CSS:

```
html, body {
    color: #333;
    background: #eee;
    font: sans-serif;
}
```

And the header.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Awesome Theme</title>
    <?php wp_head();?>
</head>
<body>
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Your style sheet url has something missing or is it a typo ? `http:/ /placeholder-url.net/wp-content/themes/awesomethemecss/awesome.css?ver=1.0.0` ? Is there any slash missing here `awesomethemecss` ?

Comment: The space between http:// is so that it doesn't underline the url. The `awesomethemecss` part must have been generated by wp, I guess? On my computer and in the ftp client the path is `wordpress\wp-content\themes\awesometheme\awesome.css`...

Comment: I mean is it `awesomethemecss/awesome.css` or `awesometheme/css/awesome.css` ?

Comment: Oh! It's `awesomethemecss/awesome.css` in the error message I'm getting from the browser. But on my computer (and in the order of upload via my ftp client), the folders are `...\wordpress\wp-content\themes\awesometheme\css\awesome.css`, in case that matters.

Comment: Yea. That's why your style is not being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error on your `wp_enqueue_script` i think.

```
wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . 'css/awesome.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all')
```

Change the above one to

```
 wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/awesome.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all')
```

This is because `get_template_directory_uri()` points to the path to your theme.

Here it is, `http:/ /placeholder-url.net/wp-content/themes/awesometheme` and inorder to point this to your stylesheet in css folder, you need to add `/css/awesome.css`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I checked my code over and over again but I just didn't see that missing / ! It's working now.

Comment: Happy to help. This is usual to miss something. Come up with a great theme, Wishes :)